# Seaborn pointplot behavior in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Hi I am following a kaggle titanic tutorial that uses seaborn and trying to do the same  plots using matplotlib

```
    grid = sns.FacetGrid(train_df, row='Embarked', size=2.2, aspect=1.6)
    grid.map(sns.pointplot, 'Pclass', 'Survived', 'Sex', palette='deep')
    grid.add_legend()
```

I want to use matplotlib functions for it. I tried using df.plot but cant seem to decide which to include in x & y and how to get subplot for Embarked

Comment: Show your matplotlib code.

Comment: What exactly is your question?